# Wi-Fi card detected only with live usb

Tags: wifi, intel, lubuntu

I've an old laptop Lifetec, I just installed Lubuntu and Wi-Fi card is not detected.
But, if I boot from usb key (using "Try Lubuntu without installing"), the Wi-Fi card is detected and it works.

The card is an Intel Pro/Wireless 2200 BG

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: By 'boot from USB Key' I suppose you mean the Lubuntu installer?

Comment: Yes, with "Try Lubuntu without installing"

Answer (score 0):

I think best way is to connect your laptop to **Ethernet port**, and update your system

```
sudo apt-get update -y
sudo apt-get upgrade -y
```

After updating Go to **Ubuntu Search** and search for Additional Drivers, opening window will list the additional drivers, this will have **wifi driver** just activate that driver

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it does not work. The only driver available is "unkown".

Comment: *Additional drivers* only shows proprietary drivers added there by the Ubuntu devs. Also, please don't use the `-y` switch unless you know *exactly* what you are doing.

Comment: I tried without use `-y` but the result is the same.